# display table can be center in Chrome, but firefox does not show it in center

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I want to have a `div` in center   **vertically and horizontally** with `display:table`, and It is working very well in chrome but Firefox not showing that correctly.

the `div` id is `#content`:

```css
#content {
    background: red;
    width: 367px;
    height: 441px;
    display: table;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" class="centered">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" id="img-logo" alt="Google logo">
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgxmc9vd/)

Comment: Doesn't look centered in Chrome to me.

Comment: @j08691 oh, Really? please zoom out

Comment: @LASH The div is, in fact, not centered in Chrome.

Comment: Why do you want to use `display:table` if the content does not have `display:table-row`?

Comment: @MrLister I just one to use of of `table-n` display to be able to use `vertical-align`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For css2, you can use `table-cell` to center contents:

```css
    #content {
        background: red;
        width: 640px;
        height: 441px;
        display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="content" class="centered">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" id="img-logo" alt="Google logo">
      <div>test</div>
    </div>
```

If you want center the `#content` on the page, add this css: `margin: 0 auto;`

See http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me. Please vote up for me, to become my reputation more that 15 to be able to vote up for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can use CSS3, then use `transform:translate`

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgxmc9vd/1/)

Comment: What does translate do?

Comment: Thank you, This is working really well man. Sorry but I just can accept one answer, your answer is good but the answer that I accepted is better for me. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
#content {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(+50%);
}
```